# QGIS Repeat Page Layout

Tags: qgis, qgis-print-layouts

I'd like to reuse a page layout across multiple pages - specifically the page border, the title, etc. Is there an easy way to do this?

Right now I'm making new pages and copy/pasting everything.

Using QGIS 3.4

Comment: Is "duplicate layout" or "save as Template" what you are after?

Comment: Those are workarounds, but ultimately create an additional layout instead of adding an identical page to my existing layout

Comment: How about the Atlas feature? https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html

Comment: That looks like what I want. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dirwin said in their comment, the Atlas feature allows you to create multiple pages with the same layout but different contents.

qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/automating_map_creation.html

(Just putting this as an answer so future searchers find it faster than I did!)

Comment: Thanks, should have added an answer. The atlas feature is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The copy and paste method you use is good, but I found that no matter how close I was in pasting on a new page I was always off by a bit.  The work around I use is Paste in Place (Ctrl+Shift+V).  Say I copied all items on Page 1, Paste in Place pastes the items exactly where I copied them from on Page 1, then in the Items browser I select each element that I just pasted and under Item Properties expand Position and Size and the first parameter is Page (the page that the position and size parameters are relative to) and select the page that I want them to be on. This moves them to that page in exactly the same page-relative position with no jogs.